# Generate map from view in Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm working on a mapbox project that requires the ability to export the current view with styles into an image to be downloaded. I've checked the static maps API, but it seems to only be able to export when given the centre point and zoom, and the mapbox component only seems to be able to export the NE and SW corner coordinates with the `map.getBounds()` function. It would be helpful to have the image as an SVG image but that isn't a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download the current map in PNG format, you can do something like this:

```
 map.once('load', () => {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = map.getCanvas().toDataURL();
    a.download = 'map.png';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a great example at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/6846/files, unfortunately it never got merged but it's still a great reference since it also includes the required Mapbox logo and attribution.